# How to Use String as a Dynamic Argument Name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, parameter-passing

I am trying to create a function which can update a given property where the name of the property is passed into the function like so:

```
function Set-UserProperty {
    param (
        [String]$Property,
        [String]$NewValue
    )

    Get-ADUser Testy.McGee -Properties $Property
    Set-ADUser Testy.McGee -$Property $NewValue
    # Set-ADUser Testy.McGee -Description $NewValue # <<<<< THIS WORKS
}

Set-UserProperty -Property "Description" -NewValue "New Description"
```

I can retrieve users just fine, but when I try setting the new `Description` I get this error:

> Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
>   '-Description'.

I also tried calling `Set-ADUser Testy.McGee $Property $NewValue`, but this just results in:

> Set-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
>   'Description'.

From the first error, it looks as though `PowerShell` is trying to execute:

`Set-ADUser "Testy.Mcgee" -Description "New Description"`, as it complains about the `'-Description'` argument.

However, when I call that exact line (`Set-ADUser "Testy.Mcgee" -Description "New Description"`) the user is updated in AD.

Am I right in thinking that because I passed the parameter in as a `[string]` I can no longer use this as a parameter-name? If so, is there some other way of achieving this (passing the argument name through a function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Set-UserProperty {
    param (
        [String]$Property,
        [String]$NewValue
    )

    Get-ADUser Testy.McGee -Properties $Property
    $Command = "Set-ADUser Testy.McGee -$Property $NewValue"
    Invoke-Expression $Command
    # Set-ADUser Testy.McGee -Description $NewValue # <<<<< THIS WORKS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx):

```
function Set-UserProperty {
    param (
        [String]$Property,
        [String]$NewValue
    )

    $SetADUserParameters = @{
        $Property = $NewValue
    }

    Get-ADUser Testy.McGee -Properties $Property
    Set-ADUser Testy.McGee @SetADUserParameters
}
```